# Make dropdown menu closing when clicking outside of it

Tags: javascript, css

https://ataqfuel.com/pages/home-page-v2

I am trying to get button 2 and 3 to close like button 1 does when clicking outside of the dropdown menu. I tried adding myFunction1 code to myFunction2 and myFunction3 code but I'm not sure if I messed up the naming or what because all the dropdowns stopped functioning then.

```js
function myFunction1() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown1").classList.toggle("show");
  document.getElementById("myDropdown1").addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  });
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn1')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content1");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}

document.getElementById("dropbtn1").addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
});

function myFunction2() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown2").classList.toggle("show");
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn2')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content2");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}

function myFunction3() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown3").classList.toggle("show");
}


window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn3')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content3");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
CSS : .dropbtn {
  margin: 5%;
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  color: gray;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover,
.dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #edeb3f;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
  min-width: 160px;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: I made you a snippet.Please edit, edit above snippet and add relevant HTML

Comment: `document.getElementById("dropbtn1").addEventListener('click',function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});` - you do not have a button with id=dropbtn1

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('.moderate .button').on('click', (event) => {
  $(event.target).siblings('.dropdown')
    .toggleClass('is-open');
});

$(document).click(function(e) {
  $('.moderate')
    .not($('.moderate').has($(e.target)))
    .children('.dropdown')
    .removeClass('is-open');
});

    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.4.0/css/bulma.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<style>
.dropdown {
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px #777;
  display: none;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 2px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.dropdown a {
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 4px;
}

.dropdown.is-open {
  display: block;
}
</style>


<div class="control moderate">
  <button class="button is-small" type="button">
        moderate
      </button>

  <div class="box dropdown">
    <ul>
      <li><a class="nav-item">edit</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav-item">delete</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav-item">block user</a>   </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="control moderate">
  <button class="button is-small" type="button">
        moderate
      </button>

  <div class="box dropdown">
    <ul>
      <li><a class="nav-item">edit</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav-item">delete</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav-item">block user</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What did you change?

Comment: i am posting new code with my other example just you can take reference from here

Comment: When you answer, please tell what you did

Comment: Hi could you please clarify?

Answer (score 0):

You can use full screen width and height fixed backdrop for that. And after backdrop click close menu. It should be something like this:

```
jQuery(".backdrop").click(function(){
  jQuery("#menu").toggleClass("open");
});
```